# How to sort data numbers with for-each group in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to sort data numbers with `xsl:for-each`?
**Input XML**

```
 <root>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6000&#x2013;6243</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>5000&#x2013;5158</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6068(e)</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6148</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6200&#x2013;6206</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6203(b)</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>480</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6500</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6450</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6500&#x2013;6592</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6501(f)(1)</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6533.5</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>10018.15</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>10018.14</bold></p>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="p">
            <xsl:sort select="number(bold)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output**

```
    <root>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>480</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>5000&#x2013;5158</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6000&#x2013;6243</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6068(e)</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6148</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6200&#x2013;6206</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6203(b)</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6450</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6500</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6500&#x2013;6592</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6501(f)(1)</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>6533.5</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>10018.14</bold></p>
    <p content-type="Sta_index2"><bold>10018.15</bold></p>
</root>
```

CODE: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/29

Comment: You would need to modify your strings to only keep the numerical part you want the sort to be applied on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sebastien has indicated in a comment, you can try to strip anything after the decimal values you want to use for sorting:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="p">
            <xsl:sort select="bold => replace('[^0-9.].*$', '') => xs:decimal()"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/30

Comment: Thanks @Martin Sir!